# Create UIView through code and add events in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have created a UIView and added label to it and latter assign it to Controller.
Now whenever I click on my View it shows me  "EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Below is my code.

```
//create a UIView in App Delegate  
UIView *viewPtr = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frmRect] autorelease];  

//created a Button and added to UIView  
UIButton *btnPointer = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];  
btnPointer.frame = cgframe; // provides both a position and a size  
[btnPointer setTitle:btnLabelText forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[btnPointer addTarget:self action:@selector(generate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[viewPtr addSubview:btnPointer];  

//Now need to add this UIView to a controller  
viewController.view = viewPtr;
```

I am able to display the button on the Form but when I click on the form or the button I get 
"EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the view in the .m file of your view controller like this.

```
    - (void)loadView
    {
        UIView *viewPtr = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

    //created a Button and added to UIView  
    UIButton *btnPointer = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];  
    btnPointer.frame = cgframe; // provides both a position and a size  
    [btnPointer setTitle:btnLabelText forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
    [btnPointer addTarget:self action:@selector(generate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [viewPtr addSubview:btnPointer];  

    //Now need to add this UIView to a controller  
    self.view = viewPtr;
[viewPtr release];
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Madhup

Answer (score 1):

Instead of use the autorelease

```
UIView *viewPtr = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frmRect] autorelease];
```

Create the UIView *viewPtr on the .h file, and only do the release in the dealloc method

So, you will have the declaration on your .h file

```
UIView *viewPtr;
```

And you .m file will be with the following lines, when you instantiate the viewPtr in the same place where you was doing previously, but without the autorelease, and the release on the dealloc method as follow:

```
viewPtr = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frmRect];
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

- (void)dealloc {
    [viewPtr release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

The autorelease is the main problem in your code, because when you do this, your UIView won't respond to any event.

Cheers,
VFN

Comment: viewController.view = viewPtr; - this line retains viewPtr, so don't think autorelease causes the problem here

Comment: Try to don't do the autorelease. you will see that the problem is there.

Comment: only to test, try to remove the autorelease, and let the view with no release calling, only for test. if it works you do what I have suggested on my answer

Answer (score 0):

What is `self` in `[btnPointer addTarget:self ...` ? Is `generate:` called? Have you tried debugging there?

Answer (score 0):

As *vfn* says, this you get the error because you release the view too early. The question I would be asking is why is this case different?

Normally in an assignment like this:

```
viewController.view = viewPtr;
```

The `viewPtr` is retained and you would be correct to release it yourself. But [look at the definition](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW2):

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *view
```

This means that any value is simply *assigned* and not automatically retained.