# Add target for UIView Programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

In my view I want to add a target which should be fired when I click the view. I can do the same through IB or I have done it for buttons even in code. However I have no idea how to do it for UIView programatically.

Anyone has done that before.

Help me.

Comment: add UIBUtton to UIView, add target for button

Comment: What target are you talking about ?? accordingly ill tell also please tell ur requirment ... thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For clicking a `UIView` you have to use `UIGestureRecognizer` or `UITouch`. This would only help in prompting an action. The `UIButton` has a selector method whereas the UIView does not have any such method. Also , this is same for `UIImageViews` etc also.

Comment: Checkout these links then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660371/how-to-add-a-touch-event-to-a-uiview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041806/create-uiview-through-code-and-add-events-in-iphone , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130496/touch-event-on-uiview :)

Answer (score 5):

You can acheive this using `UIGestureRecognizer`.

Step 1:

Add your `UIView` as a property in your viewcontroller

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *yourView;
```

Step 2:

Set `UIGestureRecognizer` for your UIView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    [self.yourView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}
```

Step 3:

Handle the click on UIView.

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    //to get the clicked location inside the view do this.
    CGPoint point = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.yourView];
}
```

Remember that A UIGestureRecognizer is to be be used with a single view.